# AWS Cloudfront with custom domain routing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, namecheap

I've got two s3 buckets and two cloudfront endpoints for each one. I want to use custom domains instead of cloudfront defaults. Right now I see there's only one way to do it - create 2 subdomains and point each one to a cloudfront endpoint respectively.

What I would want to do is to create a single subdomain, for instance storage.example.com and use the following routing for my cloudfront endpoints:

```
storage.example.com/audio  // points to the first cloudfront endpoint
storage.example.com/video  // points to the second cloudfront endpoint
```

I'm using Namecheap's DNS and SSL certificates. Is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do this with a single CloudFront distribution. You can use the CloudFront behaviors to choose the origin.
You can create a behavior for `audio/*` and use the audio bucket as the origin.

Note that the url path is not modified by the behavior so in the audio bucket all objects would need to be prefixed by `audio`. e.g. `storage.example.com/audio/some/path/audiofile.mp3` would require that the S3 object's key be `audio/some/path/audiofile.mp3`